# Creating a Timestamp VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Need Help with this Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Date + Time
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub

Sub DeleteCells()
For Each Cell In Range("B3:B25")
    If IsBlank(Cell.Value) Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The purpose of this macro is to create a timestamp. First macro works fine. If anything from row B is filled in, a timestamp will be created in row C. However, the delete cells function isn't working. I want it so that if someone deletes a cell in row B, the timestamp will also be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    'anything in ColB?
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Columns(2), Target)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing to process...

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'could be >1 cell, so loop over them...
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        'skip any cells with errors
        If c.Row>=3 And Not IsError(c.Value) Then '<<edit
            c.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value = _
                IIf(Len(c.Value) > 0, Now, "")
        End If
    Next c
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! However, I'd like to start the check for column 2 at B3. How can I fix this?